# zf2 / zf3 prefilter all input data in onBootstrap()

Tags: security, zend-framework, filter, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I wonder if it is secure enough to check and filter (override) all possible input datas (get, post, cookie, session) in onBootstrap before any process? Can I override theese input datas (in Request object)  in this way?

My application is very limited for user input data, i already use a common filter (striptags, length etc.) that has been properly for all mentioned input data type checking.

Is there any other input data type that i should check ( instead of get, post, cookie and session) ?

Is it good way anyway?

Comment: Could you add some example code or an example request with a description on what fields you want to filter?

Comment: One way to implement your filter is via the dispatch event https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#mvcevent-event-dispatch